# How to reinstall the Nvidia graphic driver in the recovery mode of Ubuntu？

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I use Titan X graphic card in Ubuntu. But it crashes yesterday and I can't login after reboot. But I am able to login in the recovery mode. I think it is the driver that caused the problem and I wish to reinstall the driver. But after selecting the root option in the recovery mode, I can't install the driver with hint "Unable to create temporary file in /tmp".
How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to remove the current drivers at all during recovery?

sudo apt-get remove nvidia*

Then check whether you can get in again.

You could also try booting up by adding "nomodeset" right after quiet-splash in the boot options in grub.

Comment: Yes, I tried and was able to uninstall the old driver.